# Birthday notification ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ive set up a system where the user signs up and in the sign up they include their birthday. How can i make it so there is some sort of notification to show it's their birthday today when for example they are going to checkout and get a discount

```
def change
  create_table :useraccount do |t|

    t.string :user
    t.string :password
    t.date   :birthday

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method like this in your useraccount model (app/models/useraccount.rb):

```
 def birthday_today?
   birthday.month == Time.now.month &&
   birthday.day == Time.now.day
 end
```

Then you could use it like this in a controller:

```
 @show_birthday_notification = Useraccount.find( useraccount_id ).birthday_today?
```

And do something like this in your view:

```
 <% if @show_birthday_notification %>
   It's your birthday!
 <% end %>
```

Comment: if i want it to notify them after they login would i add it into the login controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can check like:

```
if current_user.birthday.strftime('%d-%m') == Date.today.strftime('%d-%m')
   # your stuff
end
```

Or you can create separate method as well like **Eric Terry** suggested.